# "React Redux" toolkit not providing real time state value change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having trouble with "React-Redux toolkit". I am trying to update a state, and want to get the state value in real-time. But, it's not updating on time or it's not behaving like reactive.

```js
export const globalState = createSlice({
name: "global",
  initialState: {
    page: 8,
},
  reducers: {
    pageIncrement: (state) => {
      state.page += 8;
    },
}
})
```

Then in a component,

```js
  const page = useSelector((state) => state.global.page);
```

After incrementing the page value in a component like this,

```js
const showMore = () => {
  dispatch(pageIncrement());
}
```

The `useSelector` is not producing the `page` value in real-time. I need to press double time in beginning to make `page` value `16`, and then it's updating accordingly. It's updating the `page` value, but not in real-time.

Comment: Can you show the function ?

Comment: which function can you tell?

Comment: Show your full code for the component that has `const page = useSelector((state) => state.global.page);`